# Num Pad on Apple Keyboard in Java Application fires two events

Tags: keyboard, java, apple, netbeans

I use netbeans IDE 7.1.2 for Development on Ubuntu 12.04. When typing numbers with the num pad the digit is displayed and the cursor relocated as if used the num pad with num lock disabled.

In Eclipse the keyboard mapping is fine. All i could find on this topic is this:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=145417

I also tried using a different JVM (Oracle instead of OpenJDK) with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found keyboard options which give me acceptable results. Under *Verschiedene Optionen zur Kompatiblität* (Miscellaneous compatibility options) i enabled the settings:

- *Apple Aluminium Keyboard: PC-Tasten emulieren (Druck, Scroll Lock, Pause, NumLock)* (Apple Aluminium Keyboard: emulate PC keys (Print, Scroll Lock, Pause, Num Lock))
- *Vorgegebene Nummernblocktasten* (Default numeric keypad keys)

This also solved my problem that i couldn't copy and paste out of netbeans into a native application.